# Rails or SQL query to fetch user association data

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got three models with below fields (each field after #):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_tags, dependent: :destroy
end

class UserTag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class JourneyTag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :journey
end
```

I want to find all Journeys with tags corresponding to the user's tags - `user.user_tags`. How to fetch such data?

What I was trying to do:

```
current_user.user_tags.each do |user_tag|
  JourneyTag.where(cms_tag_id: user_tag.cms_tag_id)
end
```

Which should gives me JourneyTag with the same `cms_tag_id` as `user.user_tags` has and then I want to grab this collection of `JourneyTag` to find Journey. But above query is unuseful because it always returns some JourneyTag even if it's not matched with `user_tag.cms_tag_id`

Comment: For debug, you can add these line to your block query above `puts user_tag.cms_tag_id; puts JourneyTag.where(cms_tag_id: user_tag.cms_tag_id).to_sql`

Comment: You forgot to add the journey model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Journey.joins(:journey_tags).where(journey_tags: { cms_tag_id: current_user.user_tags.pluck(:cms_tag_id) })
```

Breaking it down:

```
current_user.user_tags #=> returns all user tag ids associated 
current_user.user_tags.pluck(:cms_tag_id) #=> gives all associated cms_tag_id in single SELECT `cms_tag_id` query 
journey_tags: { cms_tag_id: current_user.user_tags.select(:cms_tag_id) } #=> executes matching WHERE against JourneyTags
Journey.joins(:journey_tags) #=> filtered JourneyTags joins with Journey
```

Alternatively, you can try below with manual joins as:

```
Journey.joins(:journey_tags).joins('INNER JOIN user_tags on user_tags.cms_tag_id = journey_tags.cms_tag_id INNER JOIN users on user_tags.user_id = users.id')
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, you should be able to `select(:cms_tag_id)` instead of `pluck(:cms_tag_id)` in order to execute a nested query instead of a double query.

Comment: @Kache Thanks! TIL. I didn't know select would lazily convert it in single query there!